# Rule -torque-frame-count not allowed for Map

Tags: carto, cartocss

I'm simply trying to recreate a map I've already made successfully but with an updated table. I added the table to CartoDB, selected "Map View," and then selected "Torque Cat." Aside from doing those things, I've done no editing, but I'm receiving the following errors:

```
There is a problem with the map tiles. Please, check your CartoCSS style
```

And when I open the CSS Editor, I see this error:

```
line 4: Rule -torque-frame-count not allowed for Map.
```

Here's my CartoCSS:

```
/** torque_cat visualization */

Map {
-torque-frame-count:512;
-torque-animation-duration:30;
-torque-time-attribute:"cartodb_id";
-torque-aggregation-function:"CDB_Math_Mode(torque_category)";
-torque-resolution:2;
-torque-data-aggregation:linear;
}

#all_flights_201410011911_lines_smoothed_mas_pt{
  comp-op: source-over;
  marker-fill-opacity: 0.9;
  marker-line-color: #FFF;
  marker-line-width: 1.5;
  marker-line-opacity: 1;
  marker-type: ellipse;
  marker-width: 6;
  marker-fill: #FF9900;
}
#all_flights_201410011911_lines_smoothed_mas_pt[frame-offset=1] {
 marker-width:8;
 marker-fill-opacity:0.45; 
}
#all_flights_201410011911_lines_smoothed_mas_pt[frame-offset=2] {
 marker-width:10;
 marker-fill-opacity:0.225; 
}
#all_flights_201410011911_lines_smoothed_mas_pt[value=1] {
   marker-fill: #A6CEE3;
}
```

Seeing as I've done nothing but selected defaults, I'm at a loss for how to fix this.

Comment: Same problem here. line 4: Rule -torque-frame-count not allowed for Map.

Comment: it's a bug, we are working on it https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/1166

Comment: I experienced the same problem and switching from and to Torque visualization solved it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug that we already fixed (as javisantana mentioned above: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/1166).

If you're still suffering the issue though, please make sure you change to other Map Wizard and then you apply Torque Cat again. That would recreate the layer as a Torque layer and the error should no longer appear.